# Describing "inclusion" in ontologies using Protege

Tags: owl, protege, protege4

I am using Protege 4.3.0 to describe remediation activities in oil-damaged areas.
I am a complete newbie at ontologies and followed [Matthew Horridge's tutorial](http://owl.cs.manchester.ac.uk/tutorials/protegeowltutorial/resources/ProtegeOWLTutorialP4_v1_1.pdf).

He expresses the fact that every Pizza has some Toppings through the propriety hasTopping, that it has one base through hasBase etc...
I was wondering what would have been the drawbacks of creating a general property "has" and expressing the fact with

`Pizza has some Topping`

`Pizza has max 1 Base`

and so on ...

Any consideration?

Adriano

Answer (score 2):

The general rule in creating ontologies is to be as specific as possible. Based on the Pizza ontology example and the two main object properties:

```
hasTopping
hasBase
```

If you only define "has" instead of the two, it means that you can say:

```
Pizza has max 1 PizzaBase
Pizza has min 3 PizzaTopping
```

Imagine that you have FrenchPizza that is equivalent to:

```
has some (TomatoTopping and ThinBase)
```

This will result in an inconsistency, since PizzaBase and PizzaTopping are disjoint and it cannot distinguish between the property relating them. However, if you had the original two properties, this would not have occurred.

Hope this helps.

Comment: but in this case wouldn't I say: `FrenchPizza has max 1 ThinBase` and `FrenchPizza has some TomatoTopping`?

Comment: If you do, the problem still remains. The point is that you need to distinguish between the smallest details in an ontology for it to be unambiguous and consistent.

Comment: Also, since the two relations are the same, you can summarise it like I did. Conjunction in ontologies can be achieved in multiple ways.

Comment: As a simple rule of thumb: `has` could work for some cases (as any other verb), but the whole idea of the ontology is to specify as much as possible the relations. `has` could be ambiguous in some cases, therefore it is better to specify as much as possible by using `hasTopping` and `hasBase`.

Answer (score 1):

Using `has` would be fine in many situations. As opposed to what Conquering Scientist said, I see no reason to be as specific as possible. In fact, it such was the case, the Pizza ontology would not be specific enough. However, using simply the verb `has` for the name of the property would probably be prone to mistakes. But you could have a property `hasIngredient` that is more general than `hasTopping` and `hasBase`.

One advantage of defining `hasTopping` is that you can set its domain and range independently from `hasBase`, so that:

```
<p>  <hasTopping>  <t> .
```

entails:

```
<t>  a  <Topping> .
```

while:

```
<p>  <has>  <t> .
```

does not say anything about `<t>`.

In any case, you must conscious that the Pizza tutorial is not a tutorial for good ontology modelling. It is merely presenting all the features of Protégé 4. If I was selling pizzas and wanted to organise the information with SemWeb technologies, I would never use such an ontology.

Comment: Thanks Antoine, is there any good tutorial on ontologies that you'd reccomend?